# Plot GeoJSON line string on canvas using D3 projection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html5-canvas

I am trying to plot a line string on a globe created using D3, but somehow it shows up wrong.

[Demo](http://bl.ocks.org/vitohuang/a10e82eba30b357d6d4b4c58ba57f209)

Here is how the projection and path are set up

```
var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .scale(scale)
    .clipAngle(90);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection)
    .context(context);
```

Then I just draw it onto the canvas (using the path function)

```
    // the route
    context.fillStyle = '#000';
    context.strokeStyle = '#000';
    context.beginPath();
    path(route);
    context.fill();
```

The *[route](https://gist.github.com/vitohuang/a10e82eba30b357d6d4b4c58ba57f209#file-route-geojson)* variable is a GeoJSONn line string, I can plot the route on the leaflet map and everything works as expected, however when I try to draw it on the globe, it just shows up wrong.

I think it has something to do with projections, but I don't what causes this. Does anyone have any idea how can I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of filling your path drawn on the canvas, you need to just stroke it:

```
    // the route
    context.fillStyle = '#000';
    context.strokeStyle = '#000';
    context.beginPath();
    path(route);
    context.stroke();   // Just stroke the path
    //context.fill();   // You don't want to fill the path
```

This will only draw the line as expected. Have a look at this working [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DFI27XFbY2U6VDqKSD51?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you need to specify fill, just set it to the background color (here that is #ccc)

```
// the route 
context.fillStyle = '#ccc';
context.strokeStyle = '#000';
context.beginPath();
path(route);
context.fill();
context.stroke();
```